# How do i fix this error? warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main_menu’

Tags: c, linked-list

this is a b-day reminder code utilizing linkedlists

```
typedef struct node  
{  
    char name[61];  
    int month;          int day;  
    int year;  
    struct node *next;  
}node;
```

this is the list

```
typedef struct list  
{  
    node *head;  
    node *tail;  
}list;
```

this is the create list code

```
list *create_list(list *plist)  
{  
    plist->head = NULL;  
    plist->tail = NULL;  
    return plist;  
}
```

this inserts the node created to the list

```
list *insert_list(list *plist, node *pnode, node *new_node)  
{  
    new_node->next = pnode->next;  
    pnode->next = new_node;  
    if (plist->tail == pnode)  
    {  
            plist->tail = new_node;  
    }  
}
```

this is the add birthday menu

```
void add_birthday(list *List)  
{  
    char x;  
    node *data = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));  
    List = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));  
    printf("******************************************************************\n");  
    printf("                    ADD BIRTHDAY REMINDER FORM\n");  
    printf("******************************************************************\n");  
    List = insert_list(List, data, create_node(data));  
    printf("Would you like to add another(y/n)?\n");  
    scanf("%c", &x);  
    if (x=='y')  
    {  
            while (x=='y')  
            {  
                    if (x=='y')  
                    {  
                            getchar();  
                            printf("******************************************************************\n");  
                            node *data = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));  
                            List = insert_list(List, data, create_node(data));  
                            printf("Would you like to add another(y/n)?\n");  
                            scanf("%c", &x);  
                    }  
            }  
    }
    main_menu(List);  //the problem lies here
}
```

this is the main menu

```
void main_menu(list* List)  
{  
    int x;  
    printf("Welcome to myCalendar version 1.0.0\n");  
    printf("Please input the number that you wish to do:\n");  
    printf("[1] Add Birthday Reminder\n");  
    printf("[2] Delete Birthday Reminder\n");  
    printf("[3] View Calendar\n");  
    printf("[4] Quit\n");  
    scanf("%d", &x);  
    getchar();  
    switch (x)  
    {  
            case 1:  
                    add_birthday(List);  
                    break;  
            case 2:  
                    delete_reminder(List);  
                    break;  
            case 3:  
                    view_calendar(List);  
                    break;  
            case 4:  
                    free(List);  
                    break;  
        }  
}
```

this is the main

```
int main(void)  
{  
    list* List = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));  
    List = create_list(List);  
    main_menu(List);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: These are the warnings test.c:290: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main_menu’
test.c: At top level:
test.c:357: warning: conflicting types for ‘main_menu’
test.c:290: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘main_menu’ was here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the definition of `main_menu()` is after `add_birthday()`? If yes define `main_menu()` before `add_birthday()`. Also define all the methods before `main()` or atleast declare them before `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not include *.h containing main_menu() declaration into the *.c containing main() or add_birthday() or wherever points the error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared main_menu? In the absence of declaration a function is assumed to return 'int'. But, you function definition says, it is returning void. This is the cause of all the confusion.